# This part won't change color

Tags: properties, lua, roblox

I am using `rbx.lua`. Everything works except for the color changing at the bottom.

Please note that the script is not finished, I just stopped at `p1`.

```
--Variables--
local r1 = math.random(100)
local r2 = math.random(100)
local r3 = math.random(100)
local p1 = workspace.Part1
local p2 = workspace.Part2
local p3 = workspace.Part3
local c1 = game.ServerStorage.green
local c2 = game.ServerStorage.yellow
local c3 = game.ServerStorage.red
local grn = NumberRange.new(0, 45)
local ylw = NumberRange.new(46, 75)
local red = NumberRange.new(76, 100)
--Randomizing Y Vector Between 0 and 100--
p1.Size = Vector3.new(4, r1, 4)
p2.Size = Vector3.new(4, r2, 4)
p3.Size = Vector3.new(4, r3, 4)
--Setting up colors--
if p1.Size.Y == grn then
    p1.BrickColor = c1
end

if p1.Size.Y == ylw then
    p1.BrickColor = c2
end

if p1.Size.Y == red then
    p1.BrickColor = c3
end
```

Comment: Please use `code block` to post your code and don't link it. Your are more likely to get a response this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

Remove the `NumberRange` variables, and replace the `if` blocks with this:

```
if p1.Size.Y <= 45 then
    p1.BrickColor = c1
elseif p1.Size.Y <=75 then
    p1.BrickColor = c2
else
    p1.BrickColor = c3 
end
```

The `elseif` block won’t be checked unless the `p1.Size.Y` value is above `45`. Same for the else block: it won’t be entered unless the value is above `75`.

Hope that helps! You were checking to see if a specific value was equal to (`==`) a range...not if the value was *in* the range.